# Gerando campos por código ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Estou fazendo uma aplicação web com ASP.NET e C#.

Nessa aplicação eu posso cadastrar vários itens de um mesmo tipo, por isso ela tem um campo texto e um botão do lado para criar novas caixas de texto. Já trabalhei com isso em desktop app, mas não sei como gerar os campos no arquivo `.aspx`.

Como posso fazer isso? Devo fazer esse comando no `.aspx` ou no `.cs`? Como posso passar os dados depois?

Comment: Não é claro o que você está perguntado, considere reformular sua pergunta de forma mais clara e objetiva.

Comment: Eu quero gerar campos em tempo de execução, só isso

Comment: @jpklzm Deixa eu ver se entendi, você quer gerar campos dinamicamente no browser do usuário? Por favor coloque um pedaço do código que vc usa para gerar o primeiro campo, e informe se o objeto gerado será "clone" desse.

Comment: Isso mesmo @LeandroAmorim. Mas quero fazer por C# ou ASP.NET(não sei se existe essa possibilidade)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
TextBox txt = new TextBox();
txt.ID = "textBox1";
txt.Text = "helloo";
form1.Controls.Add(txt);
```

Comment: Qual foi o motivo do voto negativo nessa resposta? É importante fazer um comentário.

Comment: Eu não negativei essa resposta. Na verdade estou testando ela.

Comment: Tente Fazer respostas mais completas, além de ecrever o código escreva qual o objetivo e se for o caso explicar o que cada função utilizada (ou apenas as principais) faz, assim sua resposta terá mais qualidade

Comment: Só chama esse pequeno bloco de código no método do click do botão.

Comment: Então, quando eu tento adicionar ele pede para dizer que o campo é runat=server. Como faço isso?